# Benefits to killing invaders as a host

Tags: ps4, dark-souls-3

I'm having a hell of a time getting summoned in DS3 for the "auto summon" covenants (Blue sentinels, Darkmoon, Farron, Aldrich)

Now, I don't like PVP in this game, but the drop rate is so abysmal for the PVE farming of the items I figured I'd give it a shot.

So I have had no luck getting auto summoned, but when I invade, I seem to constantly invade worlds with 3 players, many times of which are sitting on the invasion spawn point, all toting the same gear.  I'm basically killed before I even have a chance to react.

What is the purpose of this?  Aside from the minute amount of souls that is.  Are they doing this just to troll/gank, or do the members get a covenant item out of it?

Yes, yes, I'm a jerk too for (trying) to invade - but I want my cheevos!

Comment: Just so you know, voluntarily invading (i.e. not being auto-summoned) while having those covenant items equipped will _not_ reward you with the items you're looking for. I tried that myself because I'm having issues with auto-summons as well, but I only ever got pale tongues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably had very bad luck with your invasions, as people waiting on spawn points are **99% sure gankers**. Lots of people start playing in "creative" ways such as this one when they finish the game, just to have fun.

**When you kill an invader as a host, *you get 15% of his souls the host needs to level up***, and when you kill the host as an invader, you get 4% of the souls.

You don't have to feel as a jerk, **invasions are part of the game**, even of the lore (Darkwraiths, etc.). As a host, I've got very annoyed with invaders when I have a large bunch of souls and I know I'm near a bonfire and they get to kill me, but you can't evade it. As an invader, lots of invasions are full of white phantoms, just keep in mind that they might only want to do PvE, and then there you come! I'm an honor guy, so when 4 people attack me at the same time, and without even bowing...

P.S.: Having played all the Dark Souls saga intensively, I have to say that this one has the most troll PvP I've seen.

Comment: There is a lot of noise out there also that host games that already have phantoms/mad men/invaders get queue priority when invading with the red eye orb. Not sure how true that is. A lot of people also complain about blue summons, but I run around embered with Darkmoon equipped and I get plenty of work.